# Delete data with confirmation modal

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I want to delete selected data with `confirmation modal` but somehow it only deletes the latest data not the selected data. Maybe there's something with the `JavaScript` logic but I can't seem to find anything wrong.
Here's my full code:

**Controller**:

```php
public function destroy($id) {
    User::find($id)->delete();

    return redirect('usercontrol')->with('status', 'User successfully deleted!');
}
```

**View**:

```php
<tbody>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">
                {{ $user->id }}
            </th>
            <td>
                {{ $user->first_name }} {{ $user->last_name }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ $user->email }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ $user->role }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ $user->created_at }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="users/{{ $user->id }}/edit" class="badge btn-success">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit" style="color:white"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="{{ '#' }}" class="delete-modal badge btn-danger" data-value="{{ $user->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color:white"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content shadow-sm">
            <form action="/users/{{ $user->id }}" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                @method('delete')
                @csrf
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Are you sure?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-around pt-0 border-top-0">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_user">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(document).on("click", ".delete-modal", function (e) {
        var delete_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $('button[name="delete_user"]').val(delete_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Problem is `data-target` and `modal id` naming. Read my answer, your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your modal is outside of your `for loop` and that you are trying to access the `$user` variable in your modal. At this point in time the `$user` variable contains the last element of your for loop, because your loop has already iterated. That is the reason why you are always deleting your last user.

There are 2 options:

1. Put your Modal code into your loop (this will create a modal for each entry)
2. It is good practice to only have one modal and change the values
   dinamically (like you wanted to do). But for that you will have to pass/build the correct delete URL in your on click method

Give your form an id like `id="delete-form"` afterwards in your onclick method you can set the action dinamically:

`$('#delete-form').attr('action', '/users/' + delete_id);`

Comment: hi, i've added the id in form and build the delete url but i got this error `The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.` why?

Comment: this is because this url is conflicting with some other url, may be the show url..share your route file

Comment: as @zahidhasanemon already said you might have some conflicts in your routes. Can you show your routes or probably ask a new question about the new problem?
You might also want to inspect the html structure in your browser there is sometimes the problem that the csrf and method fields are not displayed inside the <form></form> tags.

Comment: yes it turned out i have conflict with other routes. its working now thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1):

First, you did not name `data-target="#exampleModal"` it correctly. You must also enter the value of `$user->id`. Change it to `data-target="#exampleModal{{ $user->id }}"`. Like this:

```
<a href="{{ '#' }}" class="delete-modal badge btn-danger" data-value="{{ $user->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{ $user->id }}">
```

Secondly, You should put `modal` code in loop:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{ $user->id }}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content shadow-sm">
                <form action="/users/{{ $user->id }}" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                    @method('delete')
                    @csrf
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Are you sure?</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-around pt-0 border-top-0">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_user">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Also pay attention to `id` tag: `id="exampleModal{{ $user->id }}"`

Answer (score 0):

you are not updating the form action for each row. so the last row is getting deleted as the form action is `/users/{{ $user->id }}`, the last user from the for loop. change the form action on button click

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete-modal", function (e) {
    var delete_id = $(this).data('value');
    $('#delete_form').attr('action', '/users/' + delete_id);
});
```

and add an id to the form

```
<form id="delete_form" method="POST" class="d-inline">
```

> and use some descriptive name for url like `users/delete/id`

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify action part of your delete modal form, for that your HTML & jQuery code should be as below:

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm">
                        <div class="modal-content shadow-sm">
                            <form action="#" id="deleteUserForm" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                                @method('delete')
                                @csrf
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <h3 class="text-center">Are you sure?</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-around pt-0 border-top-0">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_user">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        $(document).on("click", ".delete-modal", function (e) {
            var delete_id = $(this).data('value);
            $('#deleteUserForm"]').attr('action', 'users/'+data_id);
            $('#deleteUserForm"]').submit();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `$user` variable outside the for loop to see your form `<form action="/users/{{$user->id}}" ...`

In php, the last instance of the foreach loop is always outside of scoope, which is why you don't get an error.

So you have to pass it to the dinamile using javascript.